# Is accordion for huge list recommended or not?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-centered-design, dashboard, accordion

I am working on an interview dashboard (admin side) and I need to know your feedback on accordions with a long list.

The list of candidates can reach up to 100 items.

Do you suggest that I use an accordion for that list (currently how it's shown in mockup) *or* should I go for a dedicated page with pagination?

Or do you have any other ideas?

[image: Accordion method]

Comment: Sectioned long-list data works well in an accordion

Comment: Depends on what the user is doing with this data.  Is a given user likely to want to dive into more than one of these categories?  Based on the screenshot I'm guessing no -- if I'm hiring a software developer I'm unlikely to also want to interview an accountant -- which would imply separate lists or a single filterable/searchable list would be a better design... but I'm not certain I'm interpreting the use case correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Nielsen have a [comprehensive guide on accordions](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/accordions-complex-content/), and your use case seems to be **well suited to them**.

---

Let's cross-reference your accordion with Nielsen's **Major Usability Issues with Accordions**:

> **Forcing people to click on headings one at a time to display full content can be cumbersome**

- Pass ✔
- Your use case doesn't appear to have an excessive number of headings, and the headings are logical.

> **Accordions increase interaction cost.** Readers treat clicks like currency: they don’t mind spending it if the click is worthwhile and has value.

- Pass ✔
- The only way to reduce the number of clicks would be to present all of the data on the page at once, which itself would present greater usability issues.

> **Hiding content behind navigation diminishes people’s awareness of it.**

- Pass ✔
- Your *43 candidate(s)* label makes them aware of it, if they weren't already.

> **Accessibility is an important consideration.** Pages and widgets must be coded with accessibility in mind, which is an added development effort. In contrast, plain text is inherently accessible (though it can definitely be too complicated for disabled users to understand, but that’s a standard writing issue which you should consider in any case.)

- **Depends**
- This is more a matter of implementation, though it's important to check that your accordions are accessible.

> **Printing is another consideration** that a reader correctly points out. Accordions are often not well suited for printing documents and require people to print snippets of content at a time.

- **Depends**
- If your users are likely to want to print this information, you'll need to provide them with the means to do so.